# animation in Jquery : re-arranging list item using eq?

Tags: jquery

Is there possibility of animation in re-arranging list items .

I have five list items say

```
A,B,C,D,E
```

Now On click I wanted to animate clicked list item come nicely in middle and other will also move accordingly.  order will not change so if user click on A it will be done in three step with animation

```
1) A,B,C,D,E  initial 
2) E,A,B,C,D  first step
3) D,E,A,B,C   now A is in center
```

SO no mater how many step it perform to get clicked item in center it should be smooth animation. by changing position in list it get done but can't perform animation effect on it.  Can we manage that order change in children with animation?

the code show below is based on left position but it not changing the order it only change the css and animate not actual order

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amitwork/ozLqk4tr/5/) to test

```
      $('.horizontal li').on ('click',function (e)
      {      

      $(this).animate({ left: 150 }, 'slow');

      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```

I added class 'active' to make center element highlighted on click, but i can't smoothly animate list items when i click to re-arrange list-items.

CSS

```
  .horizontal  li.active {
        /*background:#2794c7;*/
        font-weight:bold;
        color:blueviolet;
        font-size: 20px;
        /*height: 150px;*/
        /*width:150px;*/
      webkit-transform: scale(1.2) ;
      -moz-transform: scale(1.2) ;
      -ms-transform: scale(1.2) ;
      -o-transform: scale(1.2) ;
      transform: scale(1.2) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving `left` property of a relative `li`. So, it wasn't animating.
Convert `left` to `padding-left` and give `li display` property as `block`

```js
$('.horizontal li').on('click', function(e) {

  $(this).animate({
    'padding-left': '150px'
  }, 'slow');

  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.horizontal li.active {
  /*background:#2794c7;*/
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blueviolet;
  font-size: 20px;
  /*height: 150px;*/
  /*width:150px;*/
  webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="horizontal">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Rest</li>
    <li>Best</li>
    <li>Waste</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Updates to fulfill re-arrangement requirement:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".rearrangable div").each(function() {
    $(this).css("left", $(this).data('order') * 110);
  });
  $(".rearrangable div").click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('order') != 2) {
      var cur = $(this);
      $(".rearrangable div").each(function() {
        if ($(this).data('order') == 2) {
          $(this).data('order', cur.data('order'));
          return false;
        }
      });
      $(this).data('order', 2);
      $(".rearrangable div").each(function() {
        $(this).css("left", $(this).data('order') * 110);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rearrangable {
  position: relative;
}
.rearrangable div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: left 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rearrangable">
  <div data-order="0">1</div>
  <div data-order="1">2</div>
  <div data-order="2">3</div>
  <div data-order="3">4</div>
  <div data-order="4">5</div>
</div>
```

Above example used divs instead of list for achieving the rearrangement goal. Divs clicked will swap its place with Div in center.

Comment: thanks very much kiran, sorry to say but i am very frustrated with this task from month coz i am a learner and i dont know how to implement it with jQuery  so i am asking you for help me in this task My requirement  like :  have five elements   1   2    3    4   5   rearrange order like , when click on 1st element it place the position in center like as  5  4   1   2   3    with animation. I copied code from Stack overflow editable answer of the question  Jquery : Re-arranging list item using eq..

Comment: But, that is drag event and i want to shift element horizontally  one by one  on click event...

Comment: anyone here have an idea about above task to implement as i mentioned in comment....

Comment: Hi Kiran, do you have any idea about above task how to implement as i mentioned  you in comment..

Comment: Well Vikas, I was quite busy lately. I will try to help you soon. I don't find your fiddle working though.

Comment: ok Kiran, it's working in web browser after include js library in html page my fiddle is temporary... just for reference purpose...that's why... but think you understand my code.... and requirement..

Comment: Hello Kiran, any idea about my requirement?

Comment: You should not just add-on the requirements. If you feel you needed them all, you should have mentioned earlier. Just nagging someone to do your work is not helping. Try to do it yourself and then if any problem occur, then post new thread.

Comment: If you feel this thread is answered, just close the thread by accepting one as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a re-arranging of list items with animation. The requirement was that I have five elements:

```
1   2   3   4   5
```

and rearrange order like, when click on 1st element it place the position in center like this:

```
5   4   1   2  3
```

with animation. But you have any idea about shifting list items behind from Row, you can check my fiddle: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amitwork/ozLqk4tr/5/)

```js
$('.horizontal li').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    var tparent = $(this).parent();
    var childs = tparent.children().length;
    var eachWidth = this.clientWidth + 10;
    var middle = eachWidth * (parseInt(childs / 2));
    var rowChild = $(this).parent().children('li');
    var currentIndex = rowChild.index($(this));

    rowChild.each(function (li) {
        if ($(this).attr("POS")) {
            cp = $(this).attr("POS");
        } else {
            $(this).attr("POS", li);
        }
    });

    function animateEach() {
        rowChild.each(function (li) {
            var _minePos = $(this).position().left;
            var cp = $(this).attr("POS");
            var _newPos = cp * eachWidth;

            $(this).animate({
                left: (cp - li) * eachWidth,
            }, 40, function () {
                // checkPOS();
            });
        });
        setTimeout(checkPOS(true), 40);
    }

    var currentelement = $(this);
    var currentIIN = $(this).attr("POS");

    function checkPOS(ee) {
        if (currentIIN != 2) {
            rowChild.each(function (li) {
                var eachPOS = $(this).attr("POS");
                if (eachPOS >= 4) {
                    $(this).attr("POS", 0);
                } else {
                    $(this).attr("POS", parseInt(eachPOS) + 1);
                }
            });
            currentIIN = currentelement.attr("POS");
            animateEach();
        } else {
            if (ee) currentelement.addClass('active');

        }
    }

    checkPOS();
```

```css
p {
    margin: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.horizontal {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}
ul.horizontal li {
    float: left;
    /*background: #ccc;*/
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.ul.horizontal .li.a {
    border:2px solid #fb7d1e;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.horizontal li.active {
    /*background:silver;*/
    font-weight:bold;
    color:blueviolet;
    font-size: 20px;
    /*height: 150px;*/
    /*width:150px;*/
    webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    /*border:1px solid ;*/
    /*border-radius: 1em;*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
    box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
}
/*background: #ccc;*/
 display: block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 position: relative;

}
.ul.horizontal .li.a {
    border:2px solid #fb7d1e;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.horizontal li.active {
    /*background:silver;*/
    font-weight:bold;
    color:blueviolet;
    font-size: 20px;
    /*height: 150px;*/
    /*width:150px;*/
    webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    /*border:1px solid ;*/
    /*border-radius: 1em;*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
    box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
}
```

Check my [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amitwork/ozLqk4tr/5/)